# The named node is from a different document context

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, attributes, nodes

I'm trying to add an attribute to a node, and I'm getting the following error: "the named node is from a different document context"

```
Private Sub AddAttribute(ByRef node As XmlNode, ByRef file As XmlDocument, attribute As String, value As String)
    Dim myAttribute As XmlAttribute

    myAttribute = file.CreateAttribute(attribute)
    myAttribute.Value = value
    node.Attributes.Append(myAttribute)
End Sub
```

I have read about xmlNode.OwnerDocument.ImportNode but I don't find a way to do the same with attributes. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Did no answer in this list   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+named+node+is+from+a+different+document+context help you out?

Comment: The variable node must be from the same document as the variable file.  The issue is not in the code posted but in the parent code.